# I am not able to escape html in django tinyMCE

Tags: python, django

I am learning django currently and I faced this issue while trying to escape my HTML which was read from my database. I tried to use |safe in my template but it is not working.

Below is the code I am tried in my template

```
{% load static %}
<!-- Prism CSS -->
<link href="{% static "tinymce/css/prism.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
{% for tut in tutorials %}
    <p>{{tut.tutorial_title}}</p>
    <p>{{tut.tutorial_published}}</p>
    <p>{{tut.tutorial_content|safe}}</p>
    <br><br>
{% endfor %}
<!-- Prism JS -->
<script src="{% static "tinymce/js/prism.js" %}"></script>
</body>
```

My extected output is plain text without html tags

Comment: Don't use `|escape`.

Comment: Why are you using `escape` followed by `safeseq`?

Comment: Still not working @DanielRoseman

Comment: I tried removing them and edited my answer but still not working @ritlew

Comment: The `safe` filter will cause the template renderer to not escape HTML. If you want the HTML to be escaped, simply just access the variable without any tags: `{{ tut.tutorial_content }}`

Comment: I am using WYSIWYG editor and it is not working for me

Comment: <p>hello this is my second post</p> <pre class="language-markup"><code>&lt;p&gt;hello&lt;/p&gt;</code></pre>  I get texts like this @ritlew

Comment: And what did you actually want?

Comment: I want that html tags to implement in my code like for <b> I want my text to be bold @DanielRoseman

Comment: Then as I said you need `safe` without `escape`.

Comment: "trying to escape HTML" means you're trying to display the HTML code as-is. What you mean is you're trying to **not** escape the HTML (Django escapes it by default). As @DanielRoseman says, just use `|safe`.

Comment: I have edited my question with what you said but it is still not working